# what is the time complexity of the below recurrsive function

Tags: time-complexity

```
int Do(int n)
{
 if(n<=2)
  return 1;
 else
 return(Do(floor(sqrt(n))+n);
}
```

Can I take the recursive relation as `T(square root(n)+n))+1`?
If so how do I proceed further with this problem?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about homework

Comment: There is a missing bracket in the return.

Comment: We won't do you homework for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recursion won't terminate (at least in theory, which is what you are probably talking about) when it is like in your question. Reason: `n + floor(sqrt(n))` is greater than `n`.

I suppose you mean `return Do(floor(sqrt(n))) + n`. I continue with the general considerations to answer this question, but beware: There are some gaps you have to fill out yourself!

I would split up the question about run time into two parts:

- Most important: How many recursions until base case?
- How to combine all the recursions?

Number of recursions: Write `n` as a power of 2 (i.e. `n=2^(ld n)`, where `ld` denotes logarithm for base 2). Taking the square root of `n` resp. `2^(ld n)` halves the exponent. To reach the base case, we have to halve the exponent until it is less than one. This leads to the question: How often do we have to halve `ld n` until we reach something `<= 1`. The answer to this question is roughly `ld ld n`. That is, we have *roughly* `ld ld n` recursions until the base case.

Now, we do the recursions and sum up:

```
T(n) = T(2^(ld 2))
     = T(2^((ld 2)/2)) + 1
     = T(2^((ld 2)/4)) + 1 + 1
     = ...
     = T(2^((ld 2)/(2^(ld ld 2)))) + sum(1, i=0...(ld ld 2)-1)
     = 1 + (ld ld 2) - 1
```

It remains to simplify the sum and adjust the details for the `floor`-part.

Answer (score 0):

Take any number n and n = 2^k. Square root of n means you half the exponent . Therefore, there can be only O(log k) square roots .

n =2^k therefore k = log n . then O(log k) turns into O(loglogn) ...